# OCS/Lync Website presence indication

Tags: c#, javascript, sharepoint, lync, ocs

I'm building few webparts for Sharepoint and I need to show presence of users (from Lync/OCS).
When I use :

```
<img border=\"0\" height=\"12\" width=\"12\" src=\"/_layouts/images/blank.gif\" onload=\"IMNRC('" + user.Email + "')\" id=\"IMID_" + Guid.NewGuid() + "\" ShowOfflinePawn=1>&nbsp;" + user.Name + "</span>
```

It works fine and I get nice presence control with many features (name, email, I can call this person or send any message etc...) :

[image: Presence]

The problem is that it works only in IE, is there any way I can have the same features in other browsers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are are using uses ActiveX, and will only work for IE.

You can use the [HTML Presence Controls for Microsoft Lync Server 2010](http://htmlpresencecontrols.codeplex.com) if you want to support multiple browsers.

Comment: Nice, it does not have as many features as activex, but still it's the best I've seen so far :)

Answer (score 1):

Check this out : http://customsp.blogspot.com/2014/07/sharepoint-2013-lync-presence-using.html

Using this jquery plugin you can get contact card.